# Write WCF output to document

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-client

Hi I have a WCF service which is working good. for testing purpose to QC the data i would like to seriliaze the data and write it to an xml document. how can this be done.

please find the below code where im consuming the WCF service in a client app

```
Client.EMPServiceClient proxy = new Client.EMPServiceClient(); 

proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "testuser"; 
proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "password"; 

Client.EMPSearchCriteria criteria = new Client.EMPSearchCriteria(); 
criteria.EMPNumber = "01-351"; 
proxy.GetEMPData(criteria); 

Console.Write("Finish");
```

I wrote a class as below to write the output to a doc - but could some one tell me how to bridge these

```
public static void SerializeToXML(EMPData pdata) 
{ 
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(EMPData)); 
    TextWriter txtwriter = new StreamWriter(@"d:\test.xml"); 
    serializer.Serialize(txtwriter, pdata); 
    txtwriter.Close(); 
}
```

Please advice on how to write the output to an xml doc

Thanks, 
Justin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't

```
proxy.GetEMPData(criteria);
```

return something? Shouldn't you use that result?

Try...

```
Client.EMPServiceClient proxy = new Client.EMPServiceClient(); 

proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "testuser"; 
proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "password"; 

Client.EMPSearchCriteria criteria = new Client.EMPSearchCriteria(); 
criteria.EMPNumber = "01-351"; 
var data =    proxy.GetEMPData(criteria); // Change this line

SerializeToXML(data); // and adding this line

Console.Write("Finish");
```

Comment: Could you please provide a syntax in C# on how i can use proxy.GetEMPData(criteria);  data to write to a document ?

Comment: @JustinRusso you should have all the code you need. Just call `SerializeToXML`.

Comment: could you please let me know where and how i call SerializetoXML. i need the syntax(C#) and appropiate location where i need to place it .

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do this is with WCF's built-in message logging- no need to modify the app at all. This way, you're sure to get exactly the same message- otherwise your client's serialization can be affected by WCF configuration that won't apply when you serialize the message manually.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751526.aspx